# How to select 2 words in 2 different textareas using createTextRange

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, textarea, selection, textrange

I need to select some words in 2 TextArea programmatically. I am using the following javascript to select the words. The problme is that the selection persists only on the 2nd TextArea. I am using IE 6(I know it is old, but project related purpose).

```
         function abc(start1, end1){
            var textarea1ctlID = '<%=textarea1. ClientID %>';
            var textarea2ctlID = '<%=textarea2. ClientID %>';

            var txtarea1 = document.getElementById(textarea1ctlID);
            var txtarea2 = document.getElementById(textarea2ctlID);

            var start = parseInt(start1);
            var end = parseInt(end1);

            var txtarearange1 = txtarea1.createTextRange();
            txtarearange1.moveStart("Character", start1);
            txtarearange1.collapse();
            txtarearange1.moveEnd("Character", end1);
            txtarearange1.select();

            var txtarearange2 = txtarea2.createTextRange();
            txtarearange2.moveStart("Character", start1);
            txtarearange2.collapse();
            txtarearange2.moveEnd("Character", end1);
            txtarearange2.select();
        }
```

How to make the select persist in both the TextAreas

Answer (score 0):

You can't. IE only allows one selected range.